# For Kickstart installation of 20.04 is "CD-ROM" equivalent to USB?

Tags: system-installation, usb-installation, kickstart

I am running system-config-kickstart, and it's asking me to choose the installation medium  among: CD-ROM, FTP, HTTP, or Hard Drive.

If using a USB drive, should I choose CD-ROM?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? system-config-kickstart seems to be a redhat tool. https://github.com/rhinstaller/system-config-kickstart

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I am trying to achieve installation of 20.04 server on new headless hardware. I started down this path upon reading [4.6.2. Automatic Installation Using Kickstart in the Ubuntu Installation Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/ch04s06.html#kickstart). I intend to create the installation USB on an existing 20.04 system, plug it into the target system, power up the latter, and cross my fingers. I just need it to get far enough to give me ssh access.